# How to set explain option?

Tags: informix

If you issue this command to informix server, the server will just generate explain and won't run the query. Great feature if your query doesn't end at all.

```
SET EXPLAIN ON AVOID_EXECUTION;
```

If you issue this command to informix then the Explain file will be generated at that location .

```
SET EXPLAIN FILE TO 'c:\temp\sql.out';
```

But, I need both options on and I can't figure out the syntax for doing that. If I execute both statements then the latter overrides the former.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute first the `SET EXPLAIN FILE TO 'c:\temp\sql.out';`, this way you set the target.
Then you change to avoid execution : `SET EXPLAIN ON AVOID_EXECUTE;`;

Comment: thanks, also note that the option is actually "AVOID_EXECUTE" not "AVOID_EXECUTION"